# Python firebase credentials without json file

Tags: python, firebase

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo .exe, pero para ello necesito incorporar a firebase_admin las credenciales para acceder a cloud firebase. Hasta ahora lo hacía con la ruta al archivo .json pero necesito incorporarlo como un dict para evitar el uso del archivo .json.
He leído varios artículos sobre cómo hacerlo pero ninguno me ha quedado claro (no soy un experto en el tema) qué cambios debo hacer ya que simplemente copiando y pegando el contenido del archivo en la variable tiene el siguiente aspecto, pero no es válido.

```
cred=credentials.Certificate{
     "type": "######",
     "project_id": "######",
     "private_key_id": "######",
     "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----######-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
     "client_email": "######",
     "client_id": "######",
     "auth_uri": "######",
     "token_uri": "######",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "######",
     "client_x509_cert_url": "######"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solución

En realidad, esa sintaxis es casi correcta. Podrías simplemente agregar parentesis alrededor y funcionaría:

```
cred=credentials.Certificate({
     "type": "######",
     "project_id": "######",
     "private_key_id": "######",
     "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----######-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
     "client_email": "######",
     "client_id": "######",
     "auth_uri": "######",
     "token_uri": "######",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "######",
     "client_x509_cert_url": "######"
})
```

Recuerda modificar un poco el contenido del json cuando sea necesario para adaptarlo a la forma de crear los diversos objetos de Python (aunque en general, Python y json se parecen mucho en sintaxis)

**¿Por que estoy seguro de que funcionará?**

Si bien la documentación no parece decir el tipo del argumento (¿tal vez busqué en el lugar equivocado?), podemos buscar en el [código fuente](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/firebase_admin/credentials.py#L62) y encontramos dentro del constructor de Credentials estas lineas de código:

```
if _is_file_path(cert):
    with open(cert) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
elif isinstance(cert, dict):
    json_data = cert
else:
    raise ValueError(
        'Invalid certificate argument: "{0}". Certificate argument must be a file path, '
            'or a dict containing the parsed file contents.'.format(cert))
```

Que habla por si mismo.